# Dynamic View in iOS inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, autolayout

I'm creating following view (**display under *In Transit***) which are used to maintain my product status. See below image.

[image: Dyanamic Status View in Table View]

*I want to create this view in `UITableViewCell`, I have tried by placing fixed height/width view (Circle View with different color) and horizontal gray line view and it's work fine for fixed spot point.  I'm able to create this for fixed view using storyboard.*

> My Problem is, these are dynamic spot point view. Currently it's 4, but it can be vary based on status available in API response.

Anyone have idea? How to achieve this status spot dynamic view?.

Comment: Not quite clear what you're asking. Are you trying to match the "spot" positions to the Tracking Details labels? Or you can position the "spots" but you're having trouble aligning the "Circle View" over the appropriate "spot"?

Comment: @DonMag, I'm trying to position "spots" which are dynamic. Support there are more than 4 "spots" then, How can I position it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your thing using `UICollectionView` inside `UITableViewCell`.

First create following design for collection view cell. This collection view added inside table view cell.

**CollectionViewCell:**

[image: UICollectionViewCell]

See Constraints:

[image: Constraints]

Regarding spotview and circleview you can recognise by constraints and view. So don't confuse therem otherwise all naming convention are available based on view's priority.

Now you need to take outlet of collection view inside `UITableViewCell`'s subclass whatever you made and collection view cell's subview to `UICollectionViewCell`'s subclass.

**UITableViewCell:**

```
class CTrackOrderInTransitTVC: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var transitView : UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cvTransit : UICollectionView!

    var arrColors: [UIColor] = [.blue, .yellow, .green, .green]

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

Now add following code in your collection view cell subclass, It's contains outlets of your subViews of collection view cell:

```
class CTrackOrderInTransitCVC: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var leftView                     : UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightView                    : UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var spotView                     : UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var circleView                   : UIView!
}
```

Thereafter, you have to implemented table view datasource method load your collection view cell inside your table.

See the following code:

```
extension YourViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CTrackOrderInTransitTVC", for: indexPath) as! CTrackOrderInTransitTVC

        // Reload collection view to update sub views
        cell.cvTransit.reloadData()

        return cell
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `UIStackView` using "spacer" views.

Add a clear `UIView` between each "dot" view, and constrain the width of each "spacer" view equal to the ***first*** "spacer" view.

Add a `UIStackView`, constrain its width and centerY to the tracking line, and set the properties to:

```
Axis: Horizontal
Alignment: Fill
Distribution: Fill
Spacing: 0
```

Your code to add the "dots" will be something like this:

```
for i in 0..<numberOfDots {

    create a dot view

    add it to the stackView using .addArrangedSubview()

    one fewer spacers than dots (e.g. 4 dots have a spacer between each = 3 spacers), so,

    if this is NOT the last dot,

        create a spacer view

        add it to the stackView

}
```

Keep track of the spacer views, and set their width constraints each equal to the first spacer view.

Here is some starter code which may help you get going. The comments should make it clear what's being done. Everything is being done in code (no `@IBOutlet`s) so you should be able to run it by adding a view controller in storyboard and assigning its custom class to `DotsViewController`. It adds the view as a "normal" subview... but of course can also be added as a subview of a cell.

```
class DotView: UIView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.size.height * 0.5
    }

}

class TrackingLineView: UIView {

    var theTrackingLine: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        return v
    }()

    var theStack: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.axis = .horizontal
        v.alignment = .fill
        v.distribution = .fill
        v.spacing = 0
        return v
    }()

    var trackingDot: DotView = {
        let v = DotView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.5, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        return v
    }()

    let dotWidth = CGFloat(6)

    let trackingDotWidth = CGFloat(20)

    var trackingDotCenterX = NSLayoutConstraint()

    var dotViews = [DotView]()

    var trackingPosition: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            let theDot = dotViews[trackingPosition]
            trackingDotCenterX.isActive = false
            trackingDotCenterX = trackingDot.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theDot.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0)
            trackingDotCenterX.isActive = true
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        // add the tracking line
        addSubview(theTrackingLine)

        // add the "big" tracking dot
        addSubview(trackingDot)

        // add the stack view that will hold the small dots (and spacers)
        addSubview(theStack)

        // the "big" tracking dot will be positioned behind a small dot, so we need to
        //  keep a reference to its centerXAnchor constraint
        trackingDotCenterX = trackingDot.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theTrackingLine.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            theTrackingLine.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theTrackingLine.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theTrackingLine.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -20.0),
            theTrackingLine.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 2.0),

            theStack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theTrackingLine.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theStack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theTrackingLine.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theStack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theTrackingLine.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),

            trackingDotCenterX,

            trackingDot.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: trackingDotWidth),
            trackingDot.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trackingDot.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
            trackingDot.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theTrackingLine.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            ])

    }

    func setDots(with colors: [UIColor]) -> Void {

        // remove any previous dots and spacers
        //      (in case we're changing the number of dots after creating the view)
        theStack.arrangedSubviews.forEach {
            $0.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        // reset the array of dot views
        //      (in case we're changing the number of dots after creating the view)
        dotViews = [DotView]()

        // we're going to set all spacer views to equal widths, so use
        //  this var to hold a reference to the first one we create
        var firstSpacer: UIView?

        colors.forEach {
            c in

            // create a DotView
            let v = DotView()
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            v.backgroundColor = c

            // add to array so we can reference it later
            dotViews.append(v)

            // add it to the stack view
            theStack.addArrangedSubview(v)

            // dots are round (equal width to height)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: dotWidth),
                v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
                ])

            // we use 1 fewer spacers than dots, so if this is not the last dot
            if c != colors.last {

                // create a spacer (clear view)
                let s = UIView()
                s.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                s.backgroundColor = .clear

                // add it to the stack view
                theStack.addArrangedSubview(s)

                if firstSpacer == nil {
                    firstSpacer = s
                } else {
                    // we know it's not nil, but we have to unwrap it anyway
                    if let fs = firstSpacer {
                        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                            s.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fs.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
                            ])
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }

}

class DotsViewController: UIViewController {

    var theButton: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        v.setTitle("Move Tracking Dot", for: .normal)
        v.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        return v
    }()

    var theTrackingLineView: TrackingLineView = {
        let v = TrackingLineView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .white
        return v
    }()

    var trackingDots: [UIColor] = [
        .yellow,
        .red,
        .orange,
        .green,
        .purple,
        ]

    var currentTrackingPosition = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.8, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)

        view.addSubview(theTrackingLineView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theTrackingLineView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theTrackingLineView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theTrackingLineView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),
            theTrackingLineView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.9),
            ])

        theTrackingLineView.setDots(with: trackingDots)
        theTrackingLineView.trackingPosition = currentTrackingPosition

        // add a button so we can move the tracking dot
        view.addSubview(theButton)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            theButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            ])

        theButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    @objc func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) -> Void {

        // if we're at the last dot, reset to 0
        if currentTrackingPosition < trackingDots.count - 1 {
            currentTrackingPosition += 1
        } else {
            currentTrackingPosition = 0
        }

        theTrackingLineView.trackingPosition = currentTrackingPosition
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })

    }

}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for hark work. May I use this in UITableView? Because, As per my understanding `cellForRow` method shouldn't contains `for` loop. And from your code and explanation, `for` loop is required things. I have just ask to clear it.

Comment: Certainly it can be used in a table view cell. Give it a try.

Comment: Sure. I will try and let you know if any issue.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you use a collection view inside table cell, so that way you can define the position with a simple validation

Comment: Read question carefully, I'm using `UITableView`, So If I will use `UICollectionView` then It will be available inside table. I'm not aware about implementation of collection view inside table view. Could you please help me to do it?

Comment: yes its posible, I put a example in this link [link] (https://pastebin.com/vJ2NNT0v) , you can see the ViewController UITableView Delegate Extension, the TableViewCell Class and the CollectionViewCell .